# Calling Func inside Func body

Tags: c#, oop, delegates, func

I'm having some troubles, with a `Func` that I've written, the IDE doesn't like that I'm calling the `Func` inside the Func body, and I don't quite understand why because if I put this exact code in a method body instead, with the same return type and argument parameters, then it works.

Here's the code:

```
Func<XElement, TreeNode[]> arrayDel = new Func<XElement,TreeNode[]>(a => 
        {
            List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (XElement item in a.Elements())
            {
                if (item.HasElements) 
                {
                    nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.Name.ToString(), arrayDel(item))); }
                else 
                { 
                    nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.Name.ToString())); }
            }
            return nodes.ToArray();
```

Comment: code you posted works for me, seems like

Comment: @Heather Then you probably made `arrayDel` a class static/instance field. Those are always initialised, even before any explicit initialiser runs. If you make it a local variable, it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't allowed because `Func<XElement,TreeNode[]>`'s constructor *could* hypothetically call the function before `arrayDel` is initialised, meaning the function would observe an uninitialised variable.

Since *you* know that that won't happen, and that the value that `arrayDel` would have in that case is completely irrelevant, just initialise the variable to some dummy value first.

```
Func<XElement, TreeNode[]> arrayDel = null;
arrayDel = new Func<XElement,TreeNode[]>(...);
```

Comment: @Heather No, that wouldn't work. `var` takes its type from the initialiser, not from any later assignments to the variable, and `null` has no type.